# Getting error while try to connect redis using cache manager in nestjs

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, redis, nestjs

Using nestjs framework for my project and using cash manager to connect with redis cache. I am able to connect with redis but when I am using any methods like set/get it shows an error that set is not a function. added app module, service, and package json for reference

**app.module.ts**

```
import { Module, CacheModule } from '@nestjs/common';
import { AppController } from './app.controller';
import { AppService } from './app.service';
const config = require('./config');
import { Logger } from './logger';
import * as redisStore from 'cache-manager-redis-store';
import type { RedisClientOptions } from "redis"

@Module({
  imports: [
    CacheModule.register({
      // @ts-ignore
      store: async () => await redisStore({
        // Store-specific configuration:
        socket: {
          host: '******',
          port: 6380,
          password: '*****'
        }
      })
    }),
    HttpModule
  ],
  controllers: [AppController],
  providers: [AppService, Logger],
  exports: [Logger],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

**app.service.ts**

```
import { Cache } from 'cache-manager';
import {
  HttpException,
  HttpStatus,
  Injectable,
  OnApplicationBootstrap,
  OnApplicationShutdown,
  CACHE_MANAGER,
  Inject
} from '@nestjs/common';


@Injectable()
export class DeviceOnboardService
  implements OnApplicationBootstrap, OnApplicationShutdown
{

  constructor(
    @Inject(CACHE_MANAGER) private cacheManager: Cache,
    private logger: Logger
  ) {}
  
  async getData(){
    await this.cacheManager.set('test', 'XYZ', 600);
  }

}
```

**package.json**

```
"dependencies": {
    "@nestjs/common": "^8.0.0",
    "@nestjs/core": "^8.0.0",
    "cache-manager": "^5.1.3",
    "cache-manager-redis-store": "^3.0.1",
    "redis": "^4.3.1",
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@nestjs/cli": "^8.0.0",
    "@nestjs/schematics": "^8.0.0",
    "@nestjs/testing": "^8.0.0",
    "@types/cache-manager": "^4.0.2",
    "@types/express": "^4.17.13",
    "@types/jest": "27.5.0",
    "@types/node": "^16.0.0",
    "@types/supertest": "^2.0.11",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.0.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^5.0.0",
    "eslint": "^8.0.1",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.3.0",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^4.0.0",
    "jest": "28.0.3",
    "prettier": "^2.3.2",
    "source-map-support": "^0.5.20",
    "supertest": "^6.1.3",
    "ts-jest": "28.0.1",
    "ts-loader": "^9.2.3",
    "ts-node": "^10.0.0",
    "tsconfig-paths": "4.0.0",
    "typescript": "^4.3.5"
  },
```

**ERROR**

```
[Nest] 25598  - 22/11/2022, 19:32:15   ERROR store.set is not a function
```

Answer (score 2):

Async configuration needs to be configured using useFactory
,it lets you use async await and also inject services if you need to configure it dynamically

When you use useFactory, you can then use imports array and inject.
As shown in the following example, you can import configModule in the 'imports' array and configService in inject array if needed.

```
CacheModule.registerAsync<RedisClientOptions>({
  imports: [ConfigModule],
  useFactory: async (configService: ConfigService) => {
    const store = await redisStore({
      socket: {
        host: configService.get('REDIS_HOST'),
        port: configService.get('REDIS_PORT'),
      },
    });

    return {
      store: {
        create: () => store,
      },
    };
  },
  inject: [ConfigService],
})
```

You need to return store reference to create method, as can be shown in the following link, there are two types of stores [here](https://github.com/nestjs/nest/blob/8101900e137901da207da4b370aee99759767f21/packages/common/cache/cache.providers.ts#L31-L37)
then it should work